# Confusing JSONException: Expected ':' after (lots of invalid unicode characters)

Tags: android, json

Pretty straight forward question. I have no idea what this Exception means, other than there is something apparently wrong with my JSON formatting (although I doubt that is the true issue). Help is VERY appreciated.

```
    04-21 09:43:14.837: W/System.err(16240): org.json.JSONException: Expected ':' after �����������������������������������������������������... (There are about 1000 of these repeating invalid characters)
04-21 09:43:14.837: W/System.err(16240):     {
04-21 09:43:14.837: W/System.err(16240):         "id": 1560,
04-21 09:43:14.837: W/System.err(16240):         "title": "Milk Jar",
04-21 09:43:14.837: W/System.err(16240):         "description": "Milk Jar",
04-21 09:43:14.837: W/System.err(16240):         "created_at": "2014-04-10 14:32:27",
04-21 09:43:14.837: W/System.err(16240):         "submitted_by": {
04-21 09:43:14.837: W/System.err(16240):             "id": 103,
04-21 09:43:14.837: W/System.err(16240):             "name": "Cristobal Salinas",
04-21 09:43:14.837: W/System.err(16240):             "netid": "csalinas"
04-21 09:43:14.837: W/System.err(16240):         },
04-21 09:43:14.837: W/System.err(16240):         "url": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/photo/view/id/1560",
04-21 09:43:14.837: W/System.err(16240):         "image_thumb": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1560/1560-thumb.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.837: W/System.err(16240):         "image_small": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1560/1560-small.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.837: W/System.err(16240):         "image_medium": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1560/1560-medium.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.837: W/System.err(16240):         "views": 48,
04-21 09:43:14.837: W/System.err(16240):         "score": "0.4250",
04-21 09:43:14.837: W/System.err(16240):         "tags": [
04-21 09:43:14.837: W/System.err(16240):             {
04-21 09:43:14.837: W/System.err(16240):                 "id": 178,
04-21 09:43:14.837: W/System.err(16240):                 "name": "LeBaron Hall"
04-21 09:43:14.837: W/System.err(16240):             }
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         ]
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):     },
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):     {
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "id": 1559,
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "title": "Food Arch",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "description": "Food Arch",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "created_at": "2014-04-10 14:31:21",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "submitted_by": {
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):             "id": 103,
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):             "name": "Cristobal Salinas",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):             "netid": "csalinas"
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         },
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "url": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/photo/view/id/1559",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "image_thumb": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1559/1559-thumb.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "image_small": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1559/1559-small.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "image_medium": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1559/1559-medium.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "views": 44,
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "score": "0.4250",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "tags": [
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):             {
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):                 "id": 178,
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):                 "name": "LeBaron Hall"
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):             }
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         ]
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):     },
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):     {
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "id": 1558,
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "title": "Inside the Study House",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "description": "Inside the Study House",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "created_at": "2014-04-10 14:30:03",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "submitted_by": {
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):             "id": 103,
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):             "name": "Cristobal Salinas",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):             "netid": "csalinas"
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         },
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "url": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/photo/view/id/1558",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "image_thumb": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1558/1558-thumb.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "image_small": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1558/1558-small.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "image_medium": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1558/1558-medium.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "views": 51,
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "score": "0.5258",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "tags": [
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):             {
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):                 "id": 178,
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):                 "name": "LeBaron Hall"
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):             }
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         ]
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):     },
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):     {
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "id": 1556,
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "title": "Stand there",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "description": "Stand there",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "created_at": "2014-04-10 14:28:46",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "submitted_by": {
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):             "id": 103,
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):             "name": "Cristobal Salinas",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):             "netid": "csalinas"
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         },
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "url": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/photo/view/id/1556",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "image_thumb": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1556/1556-thumb.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "image_small": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1556/1556-small.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "image_medium": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1556/1556-medium.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "views": 52,
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "score": "0.4250",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "tags": [
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):             {
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):                 "id": 178,
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):                 "name": "LeBaron Hall"
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):             }
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         ]
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):     },
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):     {
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "id": 1555,
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "title": "Food Sciences CyRide",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "description": "Food Sciences CyRide",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "created_at": "2014-04-10 14:26:35",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "submitted_by": {
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):             "id": 103,
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):             "name": "Cristobal Salinas",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):             "netid": "csalinas"
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         },
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "url": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/photo/view/id/1555",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "image_thumb": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1555/1555-thumb.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "image_small": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1555/1555-small.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "image_medium": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1555/1555-medium.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "views": 46,
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "score": "0.5258",
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "tags": [
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):             {
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):                 "id": 178,
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):                 "name": "LeBaron Hall"
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):             }
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         ]
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):     },
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):     {
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "id": 1554,
04-21 09:43:14.847: W/System.err(16240):         "title": "Study House",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "description": "Study House",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "created_at": "2014-04-10 14:25:45",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "submitted_by": {
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):             "id": 103,
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):             "name": "Cristobal Salinas",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):             "netid": "csalinas"
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         },
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "url": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/photo/view/id/1554",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "image_thumb": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1554/1554-thumb.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "image_small": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1554/1554-small.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "image_medium": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1554/1554-medium.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "views": 50,
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "score": "0.2699",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "tags": [
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):             {
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):                 "id": 178,
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):                 "name": "LeBaron Hall"
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):             }
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         ]
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):     },
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):     {
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "id": 1553,
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "title": "Study Ground",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "description": "Court Yard",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "created_at": "2014-04-10 14:24:52",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "submitted_by": {
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):             "id": 103,
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):             "name": "Cristobal Salinas",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):             "netid": "csalinas"
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         },
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "url": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/photo/view/id/1553",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "image_thumb": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1553/1553-thumb.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "image_small": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1553/1553-small.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "image_medium": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1553/1553-medium.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "views": 48,
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "score": "0.2699",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "tags": [
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):             {
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):                 "id": 178,
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):                 "name": "LeBaron Hall"
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):             }
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         ]
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):     },
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):     {
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "id": 1552,
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "title": "Cherry Pie",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "description": "Full plate",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "created_at": "2014-04-10 14:22:13",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "submitted_by": {
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):             "id": 103,
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):             "name": "Cristobal Salinas",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):             "netid": "csalinas"
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         },
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "url": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/photo/view/id/1552",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "image_thumb": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1552/1552-thumb.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "image_small": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1552/1552-small.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "image_medium": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1552/1552-medium.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "views": 51,
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "score": "0.2699",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "tags": [
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):             {
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):                 "id": 758,
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):                 "name": "cherrypie"
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):             },
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):             {
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):                 "id": 178,
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):                 "name": "LeBaron Hall"
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):             }
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         ]
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):     },
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):     {
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "id": 1551,
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "title": "Bread",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "description": "Bread-cereal-rice-pasta",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "created_at": "2014-04-10 14:19:46",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "submitted_by": {
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):             "id": 103,
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):             "name": "Cristobal Salinas",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):             "netid": "csalinas"
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         },
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "url": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/photo/view/id/1551",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "image_thumb": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1551/1551-thumb.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "image_small": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1551/1551-small.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "image_medium": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1551/1551-medium.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "views": 45,
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "score": "0.2699",
04-21 09:43:14.857: W/System.err(16240):         "tags": [
04-21 09:43:14.867: W/System.err(16240):             {
04-21 09:43:14.867: W/System.err(16240):                 "id": 178,
04-21 09:43:14.867: W/System.err(16240):                 "name": "LeBaron Hall"
04-21 09:43:14.867: W/System.err(16240):             }
04-21 09:43:14.867: W/System.err(16240):         ]
04-21 09:43:14.867: W/System.err(16240):     },
04-21 09:43:14.867: W/System.err(16240):     {
04-21 09:43:14.867: W/System.err(16240):         "id": 1539,
04-21 09:43:14.867: W/System.err(16240):         "title": "Fountain of four seasons & Memorial Union",
04-21 09:43:14.867: W/System.err(16240):         "description": "Fountain of the four seasons & Memorial Union",
04-21 09:43:14.867: W/System.err(16240):         "created_at": "2014-03-21 16:45:41",
04-21 09:43:14.867: W/System.err(16240):         "submitted_by": {
04-21 09:43:14.867: W/System.err(16240):             "id": 1663,
04-21 09:43:14.867: W/System.err(16240):             "name": "Jingwei Yang",
04-21 09:43:14.867: W/System.err(16240):             "netid": "jwyang"
04-21 09:43:14.867: W/System.err(16240):         },
04-21 09:43:14.867: W/System.err(16240):         "url": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/photo/view/id/1539",
04-21 09:43:14.867: W/System.err(16240):         "image_thumb": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1539/1539-thumb.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.867: W/System.err(16240):         "image_small": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1539/1539-small.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.867: W/System.err(16240):         "image_medium": "http://photostream.iastate.edu/public/001/1539/1539-medium.jpg",
04-21 09:43:14.867: W/System.err(16240):         "views": 133,
04-21 09:43:14.867: W/System.err(16240):         "score": "0.5965",
04-21 09:43:14.867: W/System.err(16240):         "tags": [
04-21 09:43:14.867: W/System.err(16240):             {
04-21 09:43:14.867: W/System.err(16240):                 "id": 32,
04-21 09:43:14.967: D/dalvikvm(16240): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 31454K, 48% free 79977K/153564K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
04-21 09:43:14.967: I/dalvikvm-heap(16240): Grow heap (frag case) to 88.358MB for 10721502-byte allocation
04-21 09:43:14.987: D/dalvikvm(16240): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 42% free 90448K/153564K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
04-21 09:43:15.047: W/System.err(16240):      �����������������������������������������������������... (There are about 1000 of these repeating invalid characters)
04-21 09:43:15.047: W/System.err(16240):    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
04-21 09:43:15.047: W/System.err(16240):    at org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:379)
04-21 09:43:15.047: W/System.err(16240):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:100)
04-21 09:43:15.047: W/System.err(16240):    at org.json.JSONTokener.readArray(JSONTokener.java:430)
04-21 09:43:15.047: W/System.err(16240):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:103)
04-21 09:43:15.047: W/System.err(16240):    at org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:385)
04-21 09:43:15.047: W/System.err(16240):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:100)
04-21 09:43:15.047: W/System.err(16240):    at org.json.JSONTokener.readArray(JSONTokener.java:430)
04-21 09:43:15.047: W/System.err(16240):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:103)
04-21 09:43:15.047: W/System.err(16240):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:92)
04-21 09:43:15.047: W/System.err(16240):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
04-21 09:43:15.047: W/System.err(16240):    at edu.iastate.its.webdev.training.photostream.StringAsync.onPostExecute(StringAsync.java:77)
04-21 09:43:15.047: W/System.err(16240):    at edu.iastate.its.webdev.training.photostream.StringAsync.onPostExecute(StringAsync.java:1)
04-21 09:43:15.047: W/System.err(16240):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
04-21 09:43:15.047: W/System.err(16240):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
04-21 09:43:15.047: W/System.err(16240):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
04-21 09:43:15.047: W/System.err(16240):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-21 09:43:15.047: W/System.err(16240):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-21 09:43:15.047: W/System.err(16240):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-21 09:43:15.047: W/System.err(16240):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 09:43:15.047: W/System.err(16240):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-21 09:43:15.047: W/System.err(16240):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-21 09:43:15.047: W/System.err(16240):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-21 09:43:15.047: W/System.err(16240):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Just in case it'll help, here's the AsyncTask that the Exception is thrown in.

```
package edu.iastate.its.webdev.training.photostream;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class StringAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...urls) 
    {

        InputStream content = null;
        DefaultHttpClient temp = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet temp2 = new HttpGet(urls[0]);

        try {
            HttpResponse temp3 = temp.execute(temp2);
            content = temp3.getEntity().getContent();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Reader reader = null;

        try {
            reader = new InputStreamReader(content, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Large divisor otherwise Out Of Memory error occurs.
        char[] buffer = new char[Integer.MAX_VALUE/400];
        try {
            reader.read(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new String(buffer);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        if(result == null) throw new IllegalStateException("No result");
        if(result.substring(0, 3).equals("null")) result = result.substring(4, result.length()-1);

        super.onPostExecute(result);




        JSONArray arrayResult = null;
        ArrayList<PhotoItem> imageList = null;
        try {
            arrayResult = new JSONArray(result);
            if(arrayResult != null) {
                imageList = new ArrayList<PhotoItem>();
                int length = arrayResult.length();
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
                {
                    JSONObject obj = arrayResult.getJSONObject(i);
                    PhotoItem object = new PhotoItem(obj.getString("title"), obj.getInt("id"), obj.getInt("views"), obj.getString("description"), obj.getString("image_thumb"), obj.getString("image_medium"));
                    imageList.add(object);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




    }

}
```

An explaination of the error, and tips to fix it, would be very appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the JSON that is being returned? The error is saying that you have an illegal character somewhere.

Comment: Saying there are about 1000 of those invalid characters is not an exaggeration. There really are about 1000.

Comment: I thought the JSON array immediately after the first line was the one the Exception was talking about? Or does it not include the name:value pair with the illegal character?

Comment: Ok, do you know where these illegal characters are coming from? Perhaps bytes rather than characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char[] buffer = new char[Integer.MAX_VALUE/400];
try {
    reader.read(buffer);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return new String(buffer);
```

You have a huge buffer here and you are using all of it, including any uninitialized bytes to construct a `String`. It's the uninitialized data after the data filled by `read()` that contain's the nonprintable chars not understood by JSON parser.

Consider using a much smaller buffer (say, 8k) in a loop and append them to a `StringBuilder` to construct a string to return.

Comment: Yeah, this was my problem. I was having greater problems in my app that I thought involved JSON (this is my first experience with JSON, so it was a safe bet), but actually because I forgot to override getCount() in my ArrayAdapter (derp!). I was screwing around with JSON trying to figure out how in the heck it worked, which is where this came from. Everything is good now, though. Thanks for the info. :)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly your json is badly formatted.

Likely **special characters** which makes error while parsing by json parser.

Answer (score -1):

PostExecute() is meant for displaying UI. You are doing main operation in PostExecute().
Move those JSON parsing which is in postExecute to doInBackground method. Just display result in postExecute

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's question.

Comment: Good to know! However, still throwing those JSONExceptions